# C++ Error While Linking Files To Build The EXE

Tags: c++, linker

I am currently in a C++ and data structures class, but I for the life of me, can't figure out what to do about this issue I am having. The program compiles, but when I try to link the files to build a .exe, I get the following error:

```
prog9.o: In function `main':
/home/csci340/z1615629/340/assign_9/prog9.cc:20: undefined reference to `print_list<int, 4, 15>::print_list(int const&, int const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I really don't know what to do about it at all. C++ has never been my cup of tea...

My code looks like this (yes, I have commented out a good majority of the program). Side note, I don't really care whether the logic is correct or anything like that, my main focus is just to get the thing linking so I can at least run the .exe and test the output.

```
#include "/home/onyuksel/courses/340/common/340.h"

#ifndef H_PROG9
#define H_PROG9

// data files

#define D1 "/home/onyuksel/courses/340/progs/11f/p9/prog9.d1"
#define D2 "/home/onyuksel/courses/340/progs/11f/p9/prog9.d2"
#define D3 "/home/onyuksel/courses/340/progs/11f/p9/prog9.d3"

#define INT_SZ 4    // width of integer
#define FLT_SZ 7    // width of floating-pt number
#define STR_SZ 12   // width of string

#define INT_LN 15   // no of integers on single line
#define FLT_LN 9    // no of floating-pt nums on single line
#define STR_LN 5    // no of strings on single line

// function and class prototypes

// stores items from input file into vector
template <class T>
void get_list ( vector <T>&, const char* );

// construct heap from items in vector
template <class T, class P>
void construct_heap ( vector <T>&, P );

// class to compare absolute values
template <class T> class abs_less {
public:
    bool operator ( ) ( const T&, const T& ) const;
};

// structure to print items in heap, where T is data type of items,
// W is allocated size in printout, and L is max num of items printed
// on single line

template <class T, const int W, const int L>
struct print_list {
    int sz, cnt; // size of heap and counter for printing
    print_list ( const int&, const int& = 0 ); // constructor
    void operator ( ) ( const T& );
};
#endif
```

And for the .cc file.

```
#include "prog9.h"

#include "/home/onyuksel/courses/340/progs/11f/p9/prog9.h"

int main ( )
{
    vector <int>    v1;   // heap of integers
    vector <float>  v2;   // heap of floating-pt nums
    vector <string> v3;   // heap of strings

    // print header message
    cout << "\t\t\t*** CSCI 340: Program 9 - Output ***\n\n";

    // first heap

    cout << "first heap - ascending order:\n\n";
    get_list ( v1, D1 );
    construct_heap ( v1, less <int> ( ));
    print_list <int, INT_SZ, INT_LN> print1 ( v1.size ( ));
    for_each ( v1.begin ( ), v1.end ( ), print1 );

    cout << "first heap - descending order:\n\n";
    get_list ( v1, D1 );
    construct_heap ( v1, greater <int> ( ));
    for_each ( v1.begin ( ), v1.end ( ), print1 );

    cout << "first heap - ascending order with absolute values:\n\n";
    get_list ( v1, D1 );
    construct_heap ( v1, abs_less <int> ( ));
    for_each ( v1.begin ( ), v1.end ( ), print1 );

    // second heap

    cout << "second heap - ascending order:\n\n";
    get_list ( v2, D2 );
    construct_heap ( v2, less <float> ( ));
    print_list <float, FLT_SZ, FLT_LN> print2 ( v2.size ( ));
    for_each ( v2.begin ( ), v2.end ( ), print2 );

    cout << "second heap - descending order:\n\n";
    get_list ( v2, D2 );
    construct_heap ( v2, greater <float> ( ));
    for_each ( v2.begin ( ), v2.end ( ), print2 );

    cout << "second heap - ascending order with absolute values:\n\n";
    get_list ( v2, D2 );
    construct_heap ( v2, abs_less <float> ( ));
    for_each ( v2.begin ( ), v2.end ( ), print2 );

    // third heap

    cout << "third heap - ascending order:\n\n";
    get_list ( v3, D3 );
    construct_heap ( v3, less <string> ( ));
    print_list <string, STR_SZ, STR_LN> print3 ( v3.size ( ));
    for_each ( v3.begin ( ), v3.end ( ), print3 );

    cout << "third heap - descending order:\n\n";
    get_list ( v3, D3 );
    construct_heap ( v3, greater <string> ( ));
    for_each ( v3.begin ( ), v3.end ( ), print3 );

    // print termination message
    cout << "\t\t\t*** end of program execution ***\n\n";
    return 0;
}

template <class T>
void get_list ( vector <T>& v, const char* path ) {
    ifstream file;
    T data;
    v.clear()
    file.open(path);
    if(!file){
        cout << "Error opening files.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    while(file >> data){
        v.push_back(data);
    }
    file.close();
}

template <class T, class P>
void construct_heap ( vector <T>& v, P pred ) {
    if (v.empty())
        return;
    make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), pred);
}

template <class T>
bool abs_less <T> :: operator ( ) ( const T& x, const T& y ) const {
    return abs(x) < abs(y);
}

template <class T, const int W, const int L> 
void print_list <T, W, L> :: operator ( ) ( const T& x ) {
    cout << setw(W) << x;
    cnt++;
    if(cnt >= L){
        cout << "\n";
        cnt = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First off you have to understand that you're dealing with a *linker* error, not a compiler error. Second, once you appreciate that, you will know that you have to tell us your full set of build commands, as well as the *names* of your input files, because the problem is that you didn't piece everything together correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You gave the declaration of the constructor for `print_list`, but you never gave the body of it. You have to define the function, not just declare it, or your program will fail to link because the linker can't find the actual function you're trying to call.

With the line

```
print_list ( const int&, const int& = 0 );
```

You're basically saying "Ok compiler, in the future I'm going to write a function that matches this prototype, so don't yell at me when I call it." But you never do define it.

Comment: O wow, I am such an idiot. I can't believe I completely overlooked something like that... thank you. Is there a way to close this question? Haha, I must just be really out of it tonight.

Comment: IMO there is no need to close this question, however, if you can accept one of these answers that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

The message seems fairly self-explanatory.  It's saying that you haven't defined the constructor, which indeed appears to be the case!